# Quick way to override -Werror flag?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cc

If cc configuration is set to use `-Werror` is there a way to override `-Werror` flag from the terminal when using make?

Comment: Pass `-Wno-error` afterward to the compiler, probably putting in `CFLAGS` in the makefile will do.

Comment: See [Make: Override a flag](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17325955/14558) to do this in a Makefile instead of from the terminal. There’s a better answer in that case.

Comment: Finally I resolved this issue by modifying source files to remove -Werror, using this command `find . -name Makefile -or -name '*m4' -exec sed -i s/-Werror//g {} \;` Be sure to make a backup before using as it may break things. You may have to adjust `find` to find files that contains make definitions.

Answer (score 18):

You can set flags when invoking make:

```
CFLAGS=-Wno-error make
```

Comment: This probably won't work.  Most makefiles have a default setting of CFLAGS, something like `CFLAGS = -O2 -g` or something.  In order to override that you have to pass the assignment on the command line not in the environment: run `make CFLAGS=-Wno-error` instead.

Comment: @MadScientist Good point, but if you pass the CFLAGS assignment as an argument to `make` it'll clobber whatever would've been set and potentially break the build entirely (unless only `-Werror` was set).  If that's the case, then the best way is really via `./configure --extra-cflags` if available.