# Building gdb using llvm/clang

Tags: linux, gdb, clang

I'm trying to build gdb from source. I'm using "gdb 7.6 tag"

```
commit 71d22eb90be4df4b7d2dccd30caae9048289e94c
Author: Joel Brobecker <brobecker@gnat.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 26 11:43:30 2013 +0000

    NEWS: Change "since GDB 7.5" into "in GDB 7.6".
```

When i try to build it using

```
arif@khost:~/src/gdb$ clang -v
Ubuntu clang version 3.0-6ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_30/final) (based on LLVM 3.0)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

I get the following error:

```
opncls.c:263:5: error: expression result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-value]
    bfd_set_cacheable (nbfd, TRUE);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./bfd.h:529:67: note: expanded from:
#define bfd_set_cacheable(abfd,bool) (((abfd)->cacheable = bool), TRUE)
                                                                  ^
./bfd.h:134:14: note: expanded from:
#define TRUE 1
```

Comment: Stop treating warnings as errors.  [Remove `-Werror`].

Comment: This solved my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750988/quick-way-to-override-werror-flag