# Remove a compiler / linker flag from autotools configure

Tags: makefile, autotools, configure, ldflags, cflags

There is a project (Antlr3 for C) that can be built with `./configure && make && make install`.

One of the flags that are used in the compilation command is `-Wl,-soname -Wl,libantlr3c.so`. The whole command is:

```
libtool: link: gcc -shared  .libs/antlr3baserecognizer.o .libs/antlr3basetree.o \
.libs/antlr3basetreeadaptor.o .libs/antlr3bitset.o .libs/antlr3collections.o \
.libs/antlr3commontoken.o .libs/antlr3commontree.o .libs/antlr3commontreeadaptor.o \
.libs/antlr3commontreenodestream.o .libs/antlr3convertutf.o .libs/antlr3cyclicdfa.o \
.libs/antlr3debughandlers.o .libs/antlr3encodings.o .libs/antlr3exception.o \
.libs/antlr3filestream.o .libs/antlr3inputstream.o .libs/antlr3intstream.o \
.libs/antlr3lexer.o .libs/antlr3parser.o .libs/antlr3rewritestreams.o \
.libs/antlr3string.o .libs/antlr3tokenstream.o .libs/antlr3treeparser.o    \
-m64   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libantlr3c.so -o .libs/libantlr3c.so
```

How can I remove only the `-Wl,-soname -Wl,libantlr3c.so` part?

I understand that the compiler and linker flags can be overridden with `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` in the configure command. According to [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149359/what-is-the-correct-syntax-to-add-cflags-and-ldflags-to-configure), it's something like

```
./configure CFLAGS=blah LDFLAGS=blah
```

Although I understand that they can/should be used as environment variables, something like

```
CFLAGS=BLAH LDFLAGS=blah ./configure
```

However, I think that those uses would try to *override* all the `CFLAGS` or `LDFLAGS`. I only want to exclude the `-soname` flag (which, I understand, `-Wl,` means that the compiler passes a flag to the linker.

None of my attempts with things like `LDFLAGS=-soname=` or `CFLAGS="-Wl,soname -Wl,"`, and variations of them, were successful so far.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316426/make-override-a-flag) it looks as if it was possible to remove flags from within a Makefile, but I can't see that being applicable to overriding flags from the command line with the `configure` command. It's also possible to provide these variables to the `make` command instead of the `configure` command, but that wasn't successful either.

Note, it wouldn't make sense for me to change the Makefile, since it's generated out of the `configure` command.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove `-soname` because it's part of the way you build a shared library with GCC, and comes straight from `libtool`. Since you can't really build a shared object for ELF without a soname (well, you can, but it's not really useful) libtool won't let you remove that.

You probably are better off declaring what you try to achieve, because I have a feeling it has nothing really to do with `-soname` in that case.

Comment: I am familiar with this issue. Antlr3 is a dependency of a library in a package management system where dependencies are linked by providing the fully qualified path to gcc, without using -l. This hardcodes the path in the executable which in this case is exactly what we need. Only exception is when dependency is built with -soname, where not the full path is hardcoded, but the specified name. This forces us to install Antlr3 to /usr/local/lib, which clutters the environment.