# installing libcerf throws error when entering make

Tags: c

I need to use the erfi function in my C program, so I tried to install the libcerf library, where it is supposed to be contained. I downloaded it, went to the directory and entered ./configure. So far so good. Now when I enter 'make' it gives me the following error:

```
`localhost:libcerf-1.3 NAME$ make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in lib
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -pedantic -Wall -Werror -g -O2 -MT w_of_z.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/w_of_z.Tpo -c -o w_of_z.lo w_of_z.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -pedantic -Wall -Werror-g -O2 -MT w_of_z.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/w_of_z.Tpo -c w_of_z.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/w_of_z.o
w_of_z.c:79:21: error: unused function 'cpolar' [-Werror,-Wunused-function]
static inline cmplx cpolar(double r, double t)
                ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [w_of_z.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

There seems to be some problem with an unused function. This confuses me since this is the only way known to me to install libraries and I did not really do anything but the ./configure command. Yet it doesnt work. Additionally, I can't help myself with the output I get. I have tried googling it but could not get any further. I am using a Mac. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The makefile appears to set the "-Werror" flag, which turns warnings into errors. Perhaps either edit the makefile  or try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750988/quick-way-to-override-werror-flag

Comment: Thank you. It now doesnt give me an error when I try to install it but when I try to compile a test file it says this: "localhost:test NAME$ gcc -o test1 test1.c 
test1.c:54:10: fatal error: 'defs.h' file not found"
Do you know what this could mean?

Comment: It's a bit hard to guess without more info but, is there a "defs.h" file hidden somewhere in the source code directories?  It might mean that an "include path" needs setting up either in the Makefile or in the environment.